# ANTLR get first production

Tags: antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 and, in particular, the C grammar available in their repo ([grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4)). It seems that the grammar hasn't an initial rule, so I was wondering how it's possible to get it. In fact, once initialized the parser, I attach my listener, but I obtain syntax errors since I'm trying to parse two files with different code instructions:

`int a;`

```
int foo() { return 0; }
```

In my example I call the parser with `"parser.primaryExpression();"` which is the first production of the "g4" file. Is it possible to avoid to call the first production and get it automatically by ANTLR instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @GRosenberg's answer:

Also the rule enum (in the generated parser) contains entries for each rule in the order they appear in the grammar and the first rule has the value 0. However, just because it's the first rule in the grammar doesn't mean that it is the main entry point. Only the grammar author knows what the real entry is and sometimes you might even want to parse only with a subrule, which makes this decision even harder.

Comment: "[...] sometimes you might even want to parse only with a subrule". Yes, but sometimes it may not work (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281882/antlr4-not-reporting-ambiguity). ANTLR4 implicitly appends an EOF token at each rule not invoked by any other (maybe considering those rules to be roots?).

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe that. I haven't checked that specifically, but I have parsed input which contained more than what a rule can consume and that succeeded, ignoring any additional input. If there was an explicit EOF at the end of that rule it would have failed because of the extreanous input.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR provides no API to obtain the first rule.  However, in the parser as generated, the field

```
public static final String[] ruleNames = ....;
```

lists the rulenames in the order of occurrence in the grammar. With reflection, you can access the method.

Beware. Nothing in the Antlr 'spec' defines this ordering. Simply has been true to date.