# ANTLR4 not reporting ambiguity

Tags: antlr4

Given the following grammar:

```
grammar ReportAmbiguity;

unit : statements+;

statements : 
        callStatement+
        // '.'         // <- uncomment this line
    ;

callStatement : 'CALL' ID (argsByRef | argsByVal)*;

argsByRef : ('BY' 'REF')? ID+;

argsByVal : 'BY' 'VAL' ID+;

ID : ('A'..'Z')+;

WS : (' '|'\n')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

When parsing the string `"CALL FUNCTION BY VAL A B"` through the non-root rule `callStatement` everything works and the parser correctly reports an ambiguity:

```
line 1:24 reportAttemptingFullContext d=6 (argsByVal), input='B'
line 1:24 reportAmbiguity d=6 (argsByVal): ambigAlts={1, 2}, input='B'
```

Parser correcly outputs the tree: `(callStatement CALL FUNCTION (argsByVal BY VAL A B))`.

Now consider uncommenting the line shown above (the 7th). Testing everything again.

The parser still outputs the same tree, but the ambiguity reports are gone. **Why this obviously ambiguous grammar with such an ambiguous input is not being reported anymore?**

(This is part of a bigger problem. I'm trying to understand this so I can pin down another possible problem with my grammar.)

**EDIT 1**

Using antlr4 version 4.6.

I've prepared a pet project in github: https://github.com/rslemos/pet-grammars (in module `g`, type `mvn clean test -Dtest=br.eti.rslemos.petgrammars.ReportAmbiguityUnitTest` to have the commented version tested; uncomment the 7th line and run it again to see it failing).

**EDIT 2**

Changed `unit: statements*;` to `unit: statements+;`. This change itself changes nothing to the original problem. It only allows another experience (further edition pending).

**EDIT 3**

Another way to trigger this bug is to change `unit: statements+;` to `unit: statements+ unit;`.

Like when adding `'.'` to `statements`, this change also makes antlr4 forgo ambiguity detection.

I think this has something to do with an `EOF` that possibly follows `argsByVal`.

The first alternative (append `'.'` to `statements`) precludes `EOF` from appearing just after `argsByVal`.

The second one (append `unit` to itself) makes it a non-root rule (and it seems that antlr implicitly appends `EOF` to every root rule).

I always thought antlr4 rules were meant to be invoked anyway we liked, with no rule given some special treatment, the root rule being so called just because we (**grammar author**) know which rule is the root.

**EDIT 4**

Could be related to https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1545.